# How can we implement search on the encrypted data in mongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, encryption

I am using the mongoose-field-encryption package which allows me to encrypt and decrypt the data before storing and accessing it. The encrypted fields are name, email and number.
I need to implement search functionality for the encrypted fields directly in the query itself.

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'
const mongooseFieldEncryption = require("mongoose-field-encryption").fieldEncryption;
import { encryptionSecret } from '../../config'

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    match: /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    index: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  contactNumber: {
    type: String,
    default:null
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

userSchema.plugin(mongooseFieldEncryption, { 
  fields: ["email", "contactNumber"], 
  secret: encryptionSecret,
  saltGenerator: function (secret) {
    return "1452819847269312";
  },
});


const model = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export const schema = model.schema
export default model
```

```
import { User } from '.'

export const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    try {

        let { email } = req.query

        if (email) {
            const messageToSearchWith = new User({ email });
            messageToSearchWith.encryptFieldsSync();

            query.email = messageToSearchWith.email
        }

        
        let users = await User.find(query)

        return res.status(200).json(users)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in getting users', error)
    }
}
```

Above is the model and the function. Encrypted data is stored in the database but I am not able to search on the same.

I tried logging the encrypted fields, the email being saved and the encrypted email in the logs are coming out to be different. These should be same for the exact match.

I need to search over the encrypted email

Please let me know what needs to be modified to make this work as per expectations.

Comment: If the input clear text is the same, and the salt is the same, the cipher text should be the same.  Do the ingest and search use the same salt?

Comment: That regular expression for the email match seems odd, does that actually work?

Comment: try looking at Client Side Fields Level Encryption that can make filtering. I'm not a `mongoose` expert, but here you can find some insights for staring https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8167

Comment: @Joe yes, the salt is same.
Encrypted field at the time of query - 31343532383139383437323639333237:450311399d844331bba255ee5133a5460c219cf5c3eb428378c6b8b0be20e70b
Encrypted field saved in db -  31343532383139383437323639333237:0f82177498c68e314575b1b9ef1892ff